# Fedora 21 terminal based application slow response

Tags: fedora

I have recently updated to Fedora 21 Beta, and updated all packages. As the final release is scheduled early next month, I don't expect anything big to change. So I think the problem I am facing may well persist into the production release.

The problem is that when using some terminal based applications, the terminal responses very slowly. For example, say I edit a file with Vim in terminal, after a few minutes, it becomes increasingly difficult to use. Every time I hit a keystroke, the cursor will wait like a second to respond. Edit the same file (which is of only a dozen of lines) in GVim, everything works as smoothly as expected. Other terminal based applications shows the same slow response. However, using the terminal itself as an interactive shell has no problem at all.

I understand it is very hard to come by an answer to why it is experiencing this kind of slow response based only on my vague description. However, if anyone can point to where I should look for diagnostics of the problem, some log files etc., it will highly appreciated.

Below are some more details of the system.

The computer is a Dell T3500 workstation with Xeon W3550 CPU, NVIDIA Quadro 2000 GPU. I am using the latest NVIDIA binary driver (both the long live version 340.58 as well as the beta series 346.16 are tried). The open-source driver was uninstalled and its kernel module were blacklisted (`lsmod | grep nouveau` shows nothing, as expected). The desktop environment is GNOME Classic.

Comment: Just to mention that, use the same Fedora in VMware Fusion on Mac OS X Yosemite, there is no problem at all. The only difference in software is the graphics driver, one is the kernel provided VMWare graphics driver and the other is NVIDIA binary driver

Comment: What happens if you start X with the VESA driver, instead of the NVIDIA driver? (Other than it looking terrible.) And does the open-source video driver not work?

Comment: I don't remember. The first thing I did whenever I install a new fedora is to replace it with NVIDIA driver. I have replaced fedora with centos though, and everything works fine. Installing all software that I want a more recent version manually is a bit annoying, but a usable system is more important

Comment: I'm not sure if I can be of any help with my solution but I'll tell you what my problem was anyway. I had slow responses with gnome-terminal as well. I'm using the binary nvidia driver. What is really funny is that setting the powermizer to maximum performance seemed to resolve this issue. I did have another problem what my preferred terminal rxvt-unicode started up really slowly. This was caused by using xft for fonts in my Xresources file.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue is with the Nvidia driver configuration.  I know this question is old, but I was looking for a solution to the same problem in Fedora 22.  I experienced this issue when I was using Fedora 21, but I mostly put up with it.

The solution for me was to uncheck **Sync to VBlank** in the Nvidia X Server settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you running in a VM whose storage grows as you need it?  Perhaps the problem is that the VM is taking time to allocate space as your storage needs grow.  If that's the case, after a while you won't have the problem anymore, as your virtual disk will have grown as big as it needs to be.

As for diagnostics, try running "top", look for paging activity and resident set size.

Maybe something has a memory leak.  It might not be in the terminal, but in one of its dependencies.